# Can't get correct output when an equation has multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, html

The assignment calls for a calculator that understands squared numbers. To simplify the notation, a squared number is represented as X^ where X is the number you want to square.  The whole thing accepts multiple equations.  For example, if the user enters:

5^;
1000 + 6^ - 5^ + 1;

it is expected to return
25
1012.

Here's what I have:

```
    function calculate() {
        let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
        let expressions = input.split(";").filter(Boolean); // Split input into expressions
        let output = "";
        for (let expr of expressions) { // Iterate over expressions
            let tokens = expr.split(/(\+|\-|\*|\/|\^)/g).filter(Boolean); // Split expression into tokens (numbers and operators)
            let result = parseInt(tokens[0]); // Initialize result to the first number
            let operator = null;
            for (let i = 1; i < tokens.length; i += 2) { // Iterate over operators
                if (tokens[i] === "^" && tokens[i + 1] === "") {
                    result = Math.pow(result, 2);
                    continue; // Skip to next iteration
                } else if (tokens[i].match(/[\+\-\*\/\^]/)) {
                    operator = tokens[i]; // Otherwise, it's a regular operator
                }
                if (operator === "^") {
                    result = Math.pow(result, 2);
                    } else if (operator === "+") {
                        result += parseInt(tokens[i + 1]);
                    } else if (operator === "-") {
                        result -= parseInt(tokens[i + 1]);
                    } else if (operator === "*") {
                        result *= parseInt(tokens[i + 1]);
                    } else if (operator === "/") {
                        result /= parseInt(tokens[i + 1]);
                    }
                }
                output += result + "<br>"; // Append result to output with a line break
            }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output; // Display output
        }
```

As it stands, the output to the previous two equations comes out as:
25
1024206744962

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

5^;
1000 + 6^ - 5^ + 1;

It is expected to return
25
1012

However, it is returning
25
1024206744962

From what I've been told elsewhere, as a start, is my output is initialized as a string rather than a number hence the crazy output.  I can't seem to get it tweaked enough to correct it.

Comment: This doesn't look like it would support order of operations or parentheses. Also... what exactly is your input? It is unclear... surely you aren't trying to calculate 5^1000??

Comment: I think here the `^` just means square the number, not raise to the power. So it's 1000 + 6*6 - 5*5 + 1

Comment: @Anthony, by adding some print statements, you can see the output on each iteration. For example, if you print the token and the result after each loop you will see this: `token: + result: 1006,
token: ^ result: 1012036,
token: - result: 1012031,
token: ^ result: 1024206744961,
token: + result: 1024206744962,
`
That should help you with debugging. You can see here that it's adding 6 to 1000, and then it's squaring that whole number to get 1012136. So I recommend first going through and processing all the `^` operations, then doing the rest afterwards. It's an order of operations problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting an order of operations problem with your math expressions. To make this kind of math parser, you need to account for the difference between `2 + 3 * 4 = 14` vs. `(2 + 3) * 4 = 20`.

I suggest an implementation like this:

```js
const expandSquares = (input) => {
    return input.replaceAll(/(?<number>\d+)\^/g, '$1 * $1');
};

const doMultiplicationAndDivision = (input) => {
    // TODO
};

const doAdditionAndSubtraction = (input) => {
    // TODO
};

const calculateOne = (input) => {
    return doAdditionAndSubtraction(
        doMultiplicationAndDivision(expandSquares(input)),
    );
};

const calculateAll = (input) => {
    return input.split(';').map((expression) => {
        return calculateOne(expression);
    });
};
```

The idea is that you loop over your input tokens multiple times and only process certain operations. If you want correct math, you have to process multiplication and division before looking at addition and subtraction.